# SSRS: http://localhost/ReportServer accessible but no report listed

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I deployed SSRS on Windows 10 in the right way I think, at least, http://localhost/ReportServer is accessible on Internet Explorer.

As you can see in the picture below:

- I created a report using SQL Server Data Tools
- The report is there, I can also see the preview
- The Target Server URL is http://localhost/ReportServer
- But if a visit http://localhost/ReportServer there is no report

How is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was slightly easy: right click on the project > deploy.

Strange there isn't enough info on internet about a so simple glitch. :)

[image]